# SwiftUI how to display popover

Tags: swiftui, popover

Since popover presentation is deprecated in SwiftUI is there any alternative to display a view in a popover (preferably with arrow)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not deprecated. On iOS it looks equivalent to a sheet. But on iPadOS it looks like a popover with the arrow.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show popover") {
                self.showPopover = true
            }.popover(
                isPresented: self.$showPopover,
                arrowEdge: .bottom
            ) { Text("Popover") }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but I want it to display as a popover on an iPhone not as a sheet.